# Click on the menu / Slide on the screen to navigate to different pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I developed a sample website . But i need to add a feature that when i click and drag horizontally the page will turn to next page ( menu2 page on menulist ). It should happen on click and drag. When i drag reverse (left to right) page turns to previous. and also on clicking in menu button, when i click to menu 4 . the page turns to forth page on horizontal move just like on mobile devices moving on swap.

I dont know how to implement it.I am new to this field. ;-(

Comment: Did you do a search related to what you are asking?

Comment: tried but didnt get..

Comment: Ok i will try to make a fiddle.Do check for an answer later

Comment: what you tried to do? add some code and ask about it..

Comment: @user2971983 i added an answer.Check it out

Comment: You might want to check out [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)

Comment: @Alvaro ineed it horizontally.. the pages will move on x direction..

Comment: @user2971983 I know it. You can have just one section with multiple horizontal slides. Like [this page](http://www.restaurantwoods.nl/) using fullpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i created it.

### [Click to see fiddle for slide and menu scrolling](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/RL84x/)

**JQuery for scrolling by menu click**:

```
var total=$(window).width()*4;
$('.color').css({'width':''+$(window).width()+''});
$('.1').css({'position':'absolute','left':'0px'});
$('.2').css({'position':'absolute','left':''+$(window).width()+'px'});
$('.3').css({'position':'absolute','left':''+$(window).width()*2+'px'});
$('.4').css({'position':'absolute','left':''+$(window).width()*3+'px'});


$('a').click(function(){
    var num=$(this).attr('id');
    $('html').animate({'scrollLeft':''+$(window).width()*num+''});//For mozilla
    $('body').animate({'scrollLeft':''+$(window).width()*num+''});//For other browsers
});
```

**JQuery for scrolling by slide(double-click and drag for touchpads) on screen**:

```
var downX;

$('body').mousedown(function(event){
   downX=event.clientX;
});
$('body').mouseup(function(event){
    var s=$('html').scrollLeft();
    var p=$('body').scrollLeft();

    var upX=event.clientX;
    var diff=downX-upX;
    if(diff<0)
    {
  $('html').animate({'scrollLeft':''+s-$(window).width()+''});//For mozilla
  $('body').animate({'scrollLeft':''+p-$(window).width()+''});//For other browsers
    }
    if(diff>0)
    {
        var g=s+$(window).width();
        var k=p+$(window).width();
  $('html').animate({'scrollLeft':''+g+''});//For mozilla
  $('body').animate({'scrollLeft':''+k+''});//For other browsers
    }
});
```

---

### [Click to see fiddle for menu click scrolling without animation](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/8rYw4/)

**Changed** ->

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var num=$(this).attr('id');
    $('html').animate({'scrollLeft':''+$(window).width()*num+''});//For mozilla
    $('body').animate({'scrollLeft':''+$(window).width()*num+''});//For other browsers
});
```

**To** ->

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var num=$(this).attr('id');
    $('html').scrollLeft($(window).width()*num);
    $('body').scrollLeft($(window).width()*num);
});
```

Comment: dude am not aware with jquery. pls tell how can i add to this to my html?

Comment: ADD `  <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js'></script>` to the `<head> </head>` part of your page.

Comment: Open this page http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/RL84x/show/ .Right-click>view source code>Copy and paste the entire code on one page and try.

Comment: all the menus are working..:) but dragging on second page and afterwards  are not.. :(

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Solved .Check the fiddle.You can see my mail id on my profile.

Comment: @user2971983 check my updated fiddle.It now works in all browsers.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44582/discussion-between-user2971983-and-zword)

Comment: yeah... its good... working... but.. i need it.. wen am cklick on a button the pages shows as sliding just like wen we drag.. bt dont see other pages too....

Comment: Not possible because its actually the body scrolling when you slide on screen or click on the menu.When you try to jump to more than two pages left or right it will show the divs in between.And why you want more when there is enough of features in the present fiddle.The fiddles that i provided are just perfect according to me.If you try to do too much you may spoil the current one and its also difficult to handle too much animations when you are creating a project.

Answer (score 2):

If you're new you need to learn rather than implementing the technology!

However, all you need is to use mousedown and dragstart events.

If you're using jQuery then try to learn about `onDrag` event and set a function to change the page to the next menu item.